# How to set the memory for a yarn application's container different from application master

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have an application master and a yarn client based off of the code [from the Hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html). Currently the yarn client uses the same memory configuration as the application master, but I would like to provide the functionality to allow users to specify the memory requirements for *just* the containers the application is ultimately run on.

I've been looking at the Java Docs for the YarnClient and ApplicationSubmissionContext but I'm still confused on if it is possible to set the memory and vcores for just the application's container.

The YarnClient has the code:

```
// Set up the container launch context for the application master
ContainerLaunchContext amContainer = ContainerLaunchContext.newInstance(
                    localResources, env, commands, null, null, null);

// Set up resource type requirements
// For now, both memory and vcores are supported, so we set memory and
// vcores requirements
Resource capability = Resource.newInstance(amMemory, amVCores);
appContext.setResource(capability);
```

The JavaDocs state that `setResource` sets the resources required by the ApplicationMaster for this application. I think this means that I can only configure the container for the ApplicationMaster when I create the ApplicationSubmissionContext. Is that correct?

How do I specify the vcores and memory for the container that will run application in the YarnClient?

**EDIT**:

I see that the following is also set in the YarnClient. Which leads to more questions. Are the resources being set twice? Or does one portion of the code setup the container for the Application and the other the container for the Application Master?

```
// Set java executable command
LOG.info("Setting up app master command");
vargs.add(Environment.JAVA_HOME.$$() + "/bin/java");
// Set Xmx based on am memory size
vargs.add("-Xmx" + amMemory + "m");
// Set class name
vargs.add(appMasterMainClass);
// Set params for Application Master
vargs.add("--container_memory " + String.valueOf(containerMemory));
vargs.add("--container_vcores " + String.valueOf(containerVirtualCores));
vargs.add("--num_containers " + String.valueOf(numContainers));
vargs.add("--priority " + String.valueOf(shellCmdPriority));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some tests and it turns out that of the two sections of code mentioned in the question the following will set the values that the Application Master pulls from the command line to build the YARN Container for the application:

```
// Set java executable command
LOG.info("Setting up app master command");
vargs.add(Environment.JAVA_HOME.$$() + "/bin/java");
// Set Xmx based on am memory size
vargs.add("-Xmx" + amMemory + "m");
// Set class name
vargs.add(appMasterMainClass);
// Set params for Application Master
vargs.add("--container_memory " + String.valueOf(containerMemory));
vargs.add("--container_vcores " + String.valueOf(containerVirtualCores));
vargs.add("--num_containers " + String.valueOf(numContainers));
vargs.add("--priority " + String.valueOf(shellCmdPriority));
```

The code in the Application Master that obtains these values is:

```
    //getOptionValue(char opt, String defaultValue)
    containerMemory = Integer.parseInt(cliParser.getOptionValue(
        "container_memory", "1024"));
    containerVirtualCores = Integer.parseInt(cliParser.getOptionValue(
        "container_vcores", "1"));
    numTotalContainers = Integer.parseInt(cliParser.getOptionValue(
        "num_containers", "1"));
    if (numTotalContainers == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Cannot run analytic with no containers");
    }
    requestPriority = Integer.parseInt(cliParser
        .getOptionValue("priority", "0"));
```